# I need to integrate a gif player on a website to play gif and ogg file together

Tags: javascript, gif, ogg

Am currently looking at integrating a player on a website that will play a gif file and an ogg file simultaneously and i need to be able move forward, backward, play and stop

Comment: yeah i have been searching and have not seen anything that really fits

Answer (score 0):

After enough research i found this library built with angularjs and it works pretty well : https://github.com/geelen/x-gif

Cheers